# A question on elementary Weierstrass factors

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Given $E_p(z) = (1-z)\exp(\sum_{k = 1}^p \frac{z^k}{k})$, we want to show that $E_p(z) = O(z^{p+1})$. To do this, Taylor uses the following argument:

1. $\log(E_p) = \log(1-z) + \sum_{k=1}^p \frac{z^k}{k} = -\sum_{k=p+1}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{k}$, for $|z| < 1$ where the second equality sign follows from Taylor series expansion of $\log(1-z)$ about $0$.
2. And the above should imply that $E_p(z) - 1 = O(z^{p+1})$.

I am not sure why (2) (a result about the function) follows from (1) (a result about log of the function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $w \to 0$ is
$$
 e^w -1 = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{w^j}{j!} = O(w) \, .
$$
Substituting $w= \log E_p(z)$ (with $|z| < 1$) gives
$$
E_p(z)-1= e^{\log E_p(z)}-1 = O(\log E_p(z)) = O(z^{p+1}) \, .
$$

In other words: for $|z| \le R < 1$ is $|\log E_p(z)| \le K|z|^{p+1}$ with some constant $K$, and for $|w|\le K$ is $|e^w-1| \le L|w|$ with some constant $L$, so that
$$
|E_p(z)-1|= |e^{\log E_p(z)}-1 | \le L|\log E_p(z)| \le KL|z|^{p+1} \, .
$$

Comment: Do you mean $e^{log(E_p(z))} - 1 = O(\log E_p(z))$ with your substitution? I still don't understand why $O(E_p(z)) = O(z^{p+1})$ in your answer, or with my suggested correction, why $O(\log E_p(z)) = O(z^{p+1})$

Comment: @algebroo: There were some typos, sorry for that. – Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. Thank you very much for the help, I really appreciate it.